# Enable findAll function to handle > 3 digit currency

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This function works and returns the cell where a string has been found -

```
function findInAllSheets(text){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const textFinder = ss.createTextFinder(text)
  const allOccurrences = textFinder.findAll();

  const locationList = allOccurrences.map(item => {
    return {sheet:item.getSheet().getName(), cell: item.getA1Notation()}
  })
  console.log(locationList.map(object => object.cell))
  return[[locationList.map(object => object.cell).join()]] //returns the A1 notation of the specific text
}
```

However if the text being searched for is a four digit currency figure (eg $1,234.56), it isn't found. If I add quotes to the function call (eg =findInAllSheets("1,234.56") then I can get the results but this doesn't allow me to use a cell ref as the variable. Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: You might wish to add regex to your tags

Comment: Which regex are you using? Have you tried with different regex? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Note that a custom function will not update simply by editing the spreadsheet.  It will only update if the range the function references is edited or updated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- From `However if the text being searched for is a four digit currency figure (eg $1,234.56), it isn't found.`, I guessed that in this case, `=findInAllSheets("1,234.56")` of `I add quotes to the function call (eg =findInAllSheets("1,234.56") then I can get the results` might have been `=findInAllSheets("$1,234.56")`. Because when a cell shows a value of `$1,234.56`, `=findInAllSheets("1,234.56")` returns no value.
- If my understanding of your situation is correct, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to the difference between the value directly given as `"$1,234.56"` and the value given as `text` of `=findInAllSheets(A1)`.

  - In the case of `=findInAllSheets("$1,234.56")`, `text` of `findInAllSheets(text)` is a string type.
  - In the case of `=findInAllSheets(A1)` ("A1" has a value of `$1,234.56` as a number.), `text` of `findInAllSheets(text)` is a number type.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function findInAllSheets(text) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const textFinder = ss.createTextFinder(text);

  // --- I added the below script.
  if (!isNaN(text)) {
    textFinder.matchFormulaText(true).matchEntireCell(true);
  }
  // ---

  const allOccurrences = textFinder.findAll();

  const locationList = allOccurrences.map(item => {
    return { sheet: item.getSheet().getName(), cell: item.getA1Notation() }
  })
  console.log(locationList.map(object => object.cell))
  return [[locationList.map(object => object.cell).join()]] //returns the A1 notation of the specific text
}
```

- In order to search the cell value with the number format by a number, I used `matchFormulaText`.
- In this modification, when `=findInAllSheets("$1,234.56")` is used, the value is searched as a text. When `=findInAllSheets(A1)` ("A1" has a value of `$1,234.56` as a number (`1234.56`).) is used, the value is searched as a number.

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [matchFormulaText(matchFormulaText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchFormulaText(Boolean))

Answer (score 0):

If it works with the quotation marks, you can try converting your cell reference to a string with TO_TEXT:

```
=findInAllSheets(TO_TEXT(A1))
```